# Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText

Tags: android, android-layout

I am having an issue where my TextInputEditText is not being inflated on Android KitKat. The app works fine on Lollipop and newer. Upon inspecting the logcat, it appears Android KitKat doesn't know how to find vector files:

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_man_user.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f08009a
```

Even my app logo does not appear on KitKat because it is a vector. On my TextInputEditText, I have added the icons as drawableStart. It is complaining because it can't find the vectors I am referencing. Here is the XML:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"
            android:hint="@string/username_hint">
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/LoginScreenUsernameEditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_man_user"
                android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:inputType="text"
                />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"
            android:hint="@string/password_hint">
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/LoginScreenPasswordEditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_locked_padlock"
                android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                android:maxLines="1"
                />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

My app gradle file seems set up fine for vectors:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.koeksworld.homenet"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what I could do so that these vectors work on KitKat?

Answer (score 0):

Android introduced Vector support recently *(around 2 years ago i think)*. It can be enabled by adding `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` to your `build.gradle` file:

```
// Gradle Plugin 2.0+  
 android {  
   defaultConfig {  
     vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  
    }  
 }
```

You’ll note this new attribute only exists in the version 2.0 of the Gradle Plugin. If you are using Gradle 1.5 you’ll instead use

```
    // Gradle Plugin 1.5  
     android {  
       defaultConfig {  
         generatedDensities = []  
      }  

  // This is handled for you by the 2.0+ Gradle Plugin  
  aaptOptions {  
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"  
  }  
 }
```

The Android Developers blogs states that,

> If you are using AppCompat 23.2.0, setting these flags is required.
>   This requirement has been relaxed as of AppCompat 23.2.1 and the flags
>   are only required if you wish to use support vector drawables.

Due to how drawables are loaded by Android, not every place that accepts a drawable id (such as in an XML file) will support loading vector drawables. However AppCompat make it easy to use vector drawables.
When using AppCompat with ImageView (ImageButton, FloatingActionButton etc), you’ll be able to use the new `app:srcCompat` attribute to reference vector drawables:

```
 <ImageView  
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
  app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add" />
```

The blog clearly states that:

> directly referencing vector drawables outside of `app:srcCompat` will
>   fail prior to Lollipop.

Refer the [Android Developers Blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html) for more information.